# Managing data sets in SPSS where multiple cases appear in one row

Tags: reshape, spss

I'm working with a data set which has details on multiple people on one row.  How I've dealt with this is to have variables like this:

P1Name P1Age P1Gender P1Ethnicity P2Name P2Age P2Gender... etc

This makes analysis very difficult. I have used multiple response variables which are good frequencies, but its unweildy, takes time to write out the syntax (there's a lot of 'p's) and you can't do other analysis with it.

first of all is there a way to run analyses as if all the name, age, gender and so on variables are all on the same row? (if that makes sense) To do this all I can think of doing is pasting the data into Excel and then cutting and pasting to get them all into the same columns, then pasting back to SPSS. Any other ideas?

Or is this just a matter of having two datasets, one for the case details and one for the people details?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To reshape the data so all information is in the same column see the `CASESTOVARS` command.

Comment: See: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/modules/reshapel115.htm

Comment: @AndyW, I think you meant `VARSTOCASES`, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - yes you are correct, `VARSTOCASES` is what is needed here - basically the obverse of `CASESTOVARS` (if you can't tell by the name of the command!)

Answer (score 0):

Write the data out using SAVE TRANSLATE and then read it back in removing the P's, like this:

```
FILE HANDLE MyFile /NAME='/Users/rick/tmp/test.csv'.

DATA LIST FREE /p1x1 p1x2 p1x3 p2x1 p2x2 p3x3.
BEGIN DATA.
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
END DATA.
LIST.

SAVE TRANSLATE
  /OUTFILE=MyFile
  /TYPE=CSV /ENCODING='UTF8' /REPLACE
  /CELLS=VALUES.

DATA LIST FREE FILE=MyFile /x1 x2 x3.
LIST.
```

That should do it.